# Why's my game ending when it isn't supposed to?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, react-redux

I'm using redux to handle when the match is a draw in my tic tac toe game.  If the board is full and no winner is determined, then the match is supposed to be a draw.  But as of now, the match gets called a draw even when there's 3 `X`'s and 3 `O`'s.

I believe the problem is stemming from my reducer based on the output of the `console`.

I'm trying to check it `if(this.props.totalMovesValueRedux(9)) {return "draw";}`.  In other words, if the board is full, it should return `draw`.

If you take a look at the output in the `console`, `[totalMovesReducer]` jumps from `4` to `9`, ends the game, and declares that the match is a draw, which shouldn't be the case.

I tried

- `if(this.props.totalMovesValue == 9) {return "draw"}` but when I do this and the board is full, my browser crashes resulting in having to manually turning my laptop off then on again.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's `Board.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Board.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionTypes from '../../store/actions/actions';

class Board extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            turn: 'X',
            board: Array(9).fill(''),
            locked: false
        }
    }

    clicked(box) {
        if(this.props.gameEndedValue || this.state.locked) { // this.props.gameLockedValue
            return;
        }

        if(this.state.board[box.dataset.square] === '') {               
          this.state.board[box.dataset.square] = this.state.turn;
          box.innerText = this.state.turn;

          this.state.turn = this.state.turn === 'X' ? 'O' : 'X';
          this.props.totalMovesValueRedux(this.props.totalMovesValue);
        }

        let result = this.checkWinner();

        switch(result) {
            case 'X':
                this.props.gameEndedValueRedux(true);
                this.props.winnerValueRedux("X wins!");
                break;
            case 'O':
                this.props.gameEndedValueRedux(true);
                this.props.winnerValueRedux("O wins!");
                break;
            case 'draw':
                this.props.gameEndedValueRedux(true);
                this.props.winnerValueRedux("Match is a draw");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if(this.state.turn === 'O' && !this.props.gameEndedValue) {
           this.props.gameLockedValueRedux(true);
            setTimeout(() => {
                do {
                    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
                } while(this.state.board[random] !== '');

                this.props.gameLockedValueRedux(false);
                this.clicked(document.querySelectorAll('.square')[random]);
            }, 1000)
        }
    }

    checkWinner() {
        let moves = [[0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6], [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]];
        let board = this.state.board;

        for(let i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
            if(board[moves[i][0]] === board[moves[i][1]] && board[moves[i][1]] === board[moves[i][2]]) {
                return board[moves[i][0]];
            }
        }
// the problem is here
        console.log("this.props.totalMovesValue ==> " + this.props.totalMovesValue);
        if(this.props.totalMovesValueRedux(9)) {
            return "draw";
        }
   // the problem ends here
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id="game">
                <div id="state">{this.props.winnerValue}</div>

                <div id="head">
                    Tic Tac Toe
                </div>

                <div id="board" onClick={(e) => this.clicked(e.target)}>
                    <div className="square" data-square="0"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="1"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="2"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="3"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="4"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="5"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="6"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="7"></div>
                    <div className="square" data-square="8"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        winnerValue: state.winnerValue.winnerValue,
        gameLockedValue: state.gameLockedValue.gameLockedValue,
        gameEndedValue: state.gameEndedValue.gameEndedValue,
        totalMovesValue: state.totalMovesValue.totalMovesValue

    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        winnerValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionTypes.WINNER_VALUE, value}),
        gameLockedValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionTypes.GAME_LOCKED_VALUE, value}),
        gameEndedValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionTypes.GAME_ENDED_VALUE, value}),
        totalMovesValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionTypes.TOTAL_MOVES_VALUE, value})
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Board);
```

Here's `totalMovesReducer`

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions/actions';

const initialState = {
    totalMovesValue: 0
};

const totalMovesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case actionTypes.TOTAL_MOVES_VALUE:
            console.log("[totalMovesReducer] ==> " + action.value);
            return {
                ...state,
                totalMovesValue: state.totalMovesValue + 1
            };

        default:
            return state;

    }
};

export default totalMovesReducer;
```

Output in the `console`:

```
[totalMovesReducer] ==> 0
[gameLockedReducer] ==> true
[gameLockedReducer] ==> false
[totalMovesReducer] ==> 1
[totalMovesReducer] ==> 2
[gameLockedReducer] ==> true
[gameLockedReducer] ==> false
[totalMovesReducer] ==> 3
[totalMovesReducer] ==> 4
this.props.totalMovesValue ==> 4
[totalMovesReducer] ==> 9
[gameEndedReducer] ==> true
[winnerReducer] => Match is a draw
[gameLockedReducer] ==> true
[gameLockedReducer] ==> false
```

Comment: `this.props.totalMovesValueRedux` is a dispatch action. It should not be doing anything other than dispatching an action, which in return will edit your redux store. Your redux store being changed, should update props, which in turn re-render components with new updated properties.

Comment: @FrankerZ yea I get that, but I ran out of ideas in terms of how to rectify this issue hence why I used `this.props.totalMovesValueRedux(9)`

Comment: Move all your logic into your reducer: You shouldn't have anything but the barebones in your actual component, that render your board state based on the redux state. User clicks on a square? Dispatch an action, and update a value in your store. Your component re-renders, and then renders an X or O in that square.

Comment: Why are you setting it to 9 inside the if? `if(this.props.totalMovesValueRedux(9))`

Comment: Can you recreate this in a working fashion on codesandbox? I can help out if I had something to work with.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do with redux in this case?

Comment: @FrankerZ when the board is full (9 slots taken up) and there are no winners, then `match is a draw` should be displayed.  I want to do it using redux.

Comment: So now that you had a chance to go through my codesandbox: You have any questions? Does it work as expected?

Comment: @FrankerZ yes it does.  your answer actually showed me some cool new concepts I didn't know existed.  If I have questions I'll let you know.  Thanks a lot again.